# How to create tables relationship like adjacency matrix?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following problem. I need create tables for storing data like adjacency matrix. For example the images below:

[kills relationship between heroes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUvAH.png)
[Damage relationship between heroes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KgIX.png)

I need to store this relationship between the heroes.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there will be no changes to the number of rows you could store this where each row of the matrix is a row in the table.

But this is a bad idea.  Instead you want a table where each row represents all the data about a cell in the table.

In your example image you show what any of these things are so it is hard to write out all the details here.

But probable something like this:

```
damage matrix
-------------
hero1 
hero2
hero1dealt
hero1received
```

Remember in a table like this the values are repeated twice but swapped.  In one cell the you show the dealt and received values for hero1 and in another you show the dealt and received values for hero2

You only need to store these values from the point of view of one hero and then swap them for the other.

*I'm assuming this table is only damage dealt and received between the two heros -- if it has total damage then you would need 4 columns of course.*

Comment: If you can give me some example of what to study to apply this I would be grateful.

Comment: @RodrigoPraxedes -- I've added more detail to the description, please see if that is helpful.  If you ask me what to study?  I would suggest a college level programming 1 class.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a table with three columns like `killer`, `victim` and `weight`. The first row of the matrix would look like

| killer | victim | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hero1_0 | hero0_1 | 1 |
| hero1_0 | hero0_3 | 6 |
| hero1_0 | hero0_4 | 5 |
| hero1_0 | hero0_5 | 1 |
| hero1_0 | hero0_6 | 13 |
| hero0_2 | hero1_0 | 1 |
| hero0_3 | hero1_0 | 2 |
| hero0_4 | hero1_0 | 2 |
| hero0_6 | hero1_0 | 5 |

The heroes in this example are denoted in the form heroROW_COLUMN (ROW 0 ist the matrix row header and COLUMN 0 is the column header, respectively)-